# Ubuntu 14.04 server libapache2-mod-php7.0 conflict

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

I got a ubuntu 14.04 web server. I recently upgrade php to 7.0.
When I run  dpkg -s libapache2-mod-php7.0, i got the following:

```
Architecture: amd64
Source: php7.0
Version: 7.0.4-6+deb.sury.org~trusty+5
Provides: libapache2-mod-php, phpapi-20151012
Depends: libmagic1, mime-support, php7.0-cli, php7.0-common (= 7.0.4-6+deb.sury.org~trusty+5), php7.0-json, php7.0-opcache, tzdata, ucf, apache2-api-20120211, libc6 (>= 2.15), libpcre3, libssl1.0.2 (>= 1.0.2d), libxml2 (>= 2.8.0), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Suggests: php-pear
Conflicts: libapache2-mod-php5 (<< 5.6.16+dfsg-4~), libapache2-mod-php5filter (<< 5.6.16+dfsg-4~)
```

I am a little bit worried about the conflict. My server works fine, but should i remove libapache2-mod-php5 and libapache2-mod-php5filter ?

Regards,

M

Comment: you need to remove php5 specific modules and use their php7 counterparts

Comment: Thanks iam-decoder. I run sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php5, then sudo apt-get autoremove, but  dpkg -s libapache2-mod-php7.0 sitll has the same conflicts. dpkg -s libapache2-mod-php5 said this package is still install, and dpkg -s libapache2-mod-php5filter is not